# SQL oracle: How can I get the results of 4 selects statements added & subtracted to get one value with a 'WITH' keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

My code is:

```
WITH
A_EXP AS (SELECT SUM(VENDOR_ORDER_TOTAL) AS VOT
          FROM VENDOR_ORDER
          WHERE VENDOR_ORDER_STATUS = 'F'
          AND VENDOR_ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE ('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
          AND VENDOR_ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE ('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')),

B_EXP AS (SELECT SUM(SALARY_PAID) AS SP
          FROM EMP_SALARY_INFO
          WHERE FROM_DATE >= TO_DATE ('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
          AND TILL_DATE <= TO_DATE ('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')),

C_EXP AS (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(P.PAY_TYPE) * 0.10), 2) AS PT
          FROM CUSTOMER_PAYMENT P INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER O
          ON P.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID
          WHERE P.PAY_TYPE = 'CARD'
          AND O.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE ('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
          AND O.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE ('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')),

D_INC AS (SELECT SUM(ORDER_PRETAX) AS OP
          FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER
          WHERE PAY_STATUS = 'PAID'
          AND ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE ('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
          AND ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE ('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY'))

SELECT (D_INC - (A_EXP + B_EXP + C_EXP)) AS "$$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019"
FROM A_EXP, B_EXP, C_EXP, D_INC
```

The result of each select statement in the with clause returns one value. I am trying to add the expenses and subtract it from the income. When I run the whole code I am getting some error which I am unable to figure out. Am I doing something wrong? I want the result from the aliases in this format [D_INC - (A_EXP + B_EXP + C_EXP)] and I want the result to be one value, i.e.,

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
 $$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019
 --------------------------
          -1453.84
```

Comment: You mentioned that you are getting some error. Can you please share that error?

Comment: Hi Sam,use should use the (OP - (VOT + SP + PT)) with select instead of cte name in select , please check the solution i have provided.

Comment: This is the error I am getting: "ORA-00904: "C_EXP": invalid identifier"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query , in last statement of your query I have just used column name instead of `cte` name .

```
WITH A_EXP
AS (
    SELECT SUM(VENDOR_ORDER_TOTAL) AS VOT
    FROM VENDOR_ORDER
    WHERE VENDOR_ORDER_STATUS = 'F'
        AND VENDOR_ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
        AND VENDOR_ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
    )
    ,B_EXP
AS (
    SELECT SUM(SALARY_PAID) AS SP
    FROM EMP_SALARY_INFO
    WHERE FROM_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
        AND TILL_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
    )
    ,C_EXP
AS (
    SELECT ROUND((COUNT(P.PAY_TYPE) * 0.10), 2) AS PT
    FROM CUSTOMER_PAYMENT P
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_ORDER O ON P.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID
    WHERE P.PAY_TYPE = 'CARD'
        AND O.ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
        AND O.ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
    )
    ,D_INC
AS (
    SELECT SUM(ORDER_PRETAX) AS OP
    FROM CUSTOMER_ORDER
    WHERE PAY_STATUS = 'PAID'
        AND ORDER_DATE >= TO_DATE('01 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
        AND ORDER_DATE <= TO_DATE('30 SEPTEMBER 2019', 'DD MONTH YYYY')
    )
SELECT (OP - (VOT + SP + PT)) AS "$$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019"
FROM A_EXP,B_EXP,C_EXP,D_INC
```

Comment: After making the changes suggested it does not seem to be working still. When I am running this code the error I am getting is: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I got it to work with this code. The square bracket was not accepted, [$$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019]. I changed it to "$$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019" and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query for the expected result:

```sql
SELECT (OP - (VOT + SP + PT)) AS "$$ PROFIT/LOSS - SEPT 2019"
    FROM A_EXP, B_EXP, C_EXP, D_INC
```

Comment: After making the changes suggested it does not seem to be working still.

Comment: Oh then the problem is with your query only. What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Error: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I got it to work with this code. Seems like I had some unexpected character in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't specify the column names in the final select statement. Which generate the strange error statement if you specified the columns names your query should run. Here is my trial:

```
with
    a_exp as ( select 2 as vot)
    ,b_exp as (select 3 as sp)
    ,c_exp as (select 1 as pt)
    ,d_exp as (select 10 as op)
    select (d_exp.op - (a_exp.vot +b_exp.sp+c_exp.pt))
    from a_exp,b_exp,c_exp,d_exp
```

Comment: After making the changes suggested it does not seem to be working still. When I am running this code the error I am getting is: "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: I got it to work with this code. Seems like I had some unexpected character in my code.